# How to set character encoding in Angular2Csv export?

Tags: angular, character-encoding, angular5, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I'm trying to download data into a CSV file on my angular application, however, i'm not able to display special characters like `é à ç è`  properly.

How can i set the character encoding to **UTF-8** while using **Angular2Csv** ?

I've tried to use **encoding()** and **encodingUI()** but it didn't work.  [image: I get wierd characters like this]

```
   this.options = {
  fieldSeparator: ';',
  quoteStrings: '"',
  decimalseparator: '.',
  showLabels: true,
  headers: ['Prénom', 'Référence', 'montant', 'Devise', 'Date', 'Date échéance'],
  useBom: false,
};

download(myData) {
let date = new Date();
new Angular2Csv(myData, 'MyCsv' + date.getHours() + '|' + date.getMinutes() + '|' + date.getSeconds(), this.options);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (https://github.com/javiertelioz/angular2-csv)

> useBom    true    If true, adds a BOM character at the start of the CSV